# SQL ROW_NUMBER adding to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, row-number

I have a table that has a unique ID column which is an int. This doesn't necessarily contain all numbers up to the maximum, some are missed out (it isn't an identity column - out of my control).

I need to SELECT some existing lines from that table and add them to the end changing one column's data, with each row having a new ID, incrementing up from the MAX ID. Something like this:

```
declare @maxID int;
set @maxID = (select MAX("ID") from "table");

insert into "table"
select @maxID + ROW_NUMBER, 'newData', "col3", "col4"
from "table" where "col2" = 'oldData';
```

However, I'm not sure where to take it from here - the ROW_NUMBER requires an OVER statement which I honestly don't understand in this context.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put order of which ROW_NUMBER will generate numbers. Existing ID is good option here.

```
declare @maxID int;
set @maxID = (select MAX("ID") from "table");

insert into "table"
select @maxID + ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY "ID"), 'newData', "col3", "col4"
from "table" where "col2" = 'oldData';
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you elaborate a bit more about why an OVER statement is needed, instead of is simply enumerating the SELECT results?

Comment: Well, the `ROW_NUMBER` syntax requires the `OVER` keyword. It can't be any simpler than this. `ORDER BY` is required because `ROW_NUMBER` wouldn't know on which order to enumerate.

Comment: There is no 'natural' order to rows in a database logically (although we humans tend to see the natural order as the same as the clustered index order), so the ROW_NUMBER needs to have some clue as to what order you want to see the records.

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest sense the OVER clause just specifies what column to order the rows in

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [primarykey])
```

will give you a 'gap free' surrogate primary key